# Programmatic performance of a Java method

Tags: java, performance

Two way of doing things and I'm curious which is faster:

First way:

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get(key).addAll(someList);
```

Second way:

```
List<String> existingList = map.get(key);
if (existingList == null){
    existingList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
existingList.addAll(someList);
map.put(key, existingList);
```

The first way would seem to involve having to hash the key more often, but require less object creation than the second way.  It seems to me that the second way might be faster but more resource intensive than the first way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modified version of your second way would be optimal:

```
List<String> existingList = map.get(key);
if (existingList == null){
   existingList = new ArrayList<String>();
   map.put(key, existingList);
}
existingList.addAll(someList);
```

This ensures that a lookup is only done once, and the `List` is only instantiated and put in the `Map` when necessary.

**EDIT:** As [@Martijn Courteaux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155137/martijn-courteaux) noted, a second lookup is done by `put()` when the key is not found.

Comment: `Map.put` performs a lookup as well. So, this ensures that the a lookup is only performed once, **when the key is present**.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux - thanks for pointing that out, answer edited.